# No pushpin when using MapsTask on WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I can't see the pushpin using MapsTask, the map is ok, but no pushpin on the map, anyone knows why? thank you!

```
        if (geo != null)
        {
            MapsTask mapsTask = new MapsTask();
            mapsTask.Center = geo;
            mapsTask.ZoomLevel = 15;
            mapsTask.Show();
        }
```

Comment: I am not sure. But i suggest you use Bing map instead of MapsTask. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207045(v=vs.105).aspx go with link, here more about maps and navigations.

Comment: I have tried BingMapsTask, it is the same as MapsTask, no pushpin.

Comment: Yes there is no pushpin but Maplayer is exist that same as pushpin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use mapTask.SearchTerm, the first result will show on the map with the pushpin.

mapsTask has few APIs to do more works.
If you want multiple pushpins or customize for more info,use [map control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207045%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and design it in xaml and .cs file.

here is a good example:
http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/windows-phone-drawing-custom-pushpins-on-the-map-control-what-options-do-we-have

hopes it helps.

Comment: As your suggestion, I created a map control, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
ReverseGeocodeQuery query = new ReverseGeocodeQuery();
query.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(lat, longitude);
query.QueryCompleted += (s, e) =>
     {
         if (e.Error != null)
             return;
         searchTerm = e.Result[0].Information.Address.Street; // task.SearchTerm will contain the result of address
     };
```

Now , you have the search Term , in MapsTask class, just assign

```
MapsTask task = new MapsTask();
task.SearchTerm  = searchTerm;
```

This should work fine.